# Not Found manually added new page in Yii2 with urlManager?

Tags: yii2, yii2-urlmanager

In Yii2, I have manually added a new page `backend/views/site/new.php`.

Then I have given a link in the page `backend/views/site/index.php`:

```
<a href="<?= Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('site/new'); ?>"> New</a>
```

When I click the link it shows:

> Not Found (#404)

What's the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create action in `SiteController.php` like below

```
public function actionNew()
{
    return $this->render('new');
}
```

And also create `new.php` file in `views/site/new.php`

Add `New` page link in the page `backend/views/site/index.php` like

```
<?= Html::a('New', ['new']) ?>
```